# Site goes down due to lucene

Tags: sitecore

We are getting one strange issue. Our site goes down randomly and we have following in log.

> 8764 2016-09-27 00:38:26 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (team_web_index): +(+(+(+_template:e47e40afb7c049af902feb8741bc6463 +_language:en) +_latestversion:1) +attachedfilters:*404da894ac6742f18f80132d9600238d*) +entitydate:[* TO 20160927} - Filter :
>
> 8764 2016-09-27 00:38:26 INFO  Trace: 8764 2016-09-27 00:38:26 INFO  ExecuteQueryAgainstLucene (team_web_index): +(+(+(+_template:e47e40afb7c049af902feb8741bc6463 +_language:en) +_latestversion:1) +attachedfilters:*404da894ac6742f18f80132d9600238d*) +entitydate:[20160927 TO *] - Filter :

this is definitely due to Lucene index but what can be possible reason.

Comment: This is just INFO and TRACE log. Why do you think it's the reason of your issues?

Comment: Make sure that there is nothing suspicious in your **Event Viewer** logs (Windows Logs->Application). If site goes down and there is nothing in Sitecore logs it might be stack overflow exception for example.